# Android SKD wont download anything (Ubuntu 12.04 LST)

Tags: android, proxy, ubuntu-12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LST 64-bit, and I installed Eclipse and downloaded and extracted Android SDK. When I try to install ADT plugin for Eclipse or to download packages with Android SDK Manager nothing happens, precisely it wont connect to the google server. My network is ADSL and it  uses proxy server and probably that is the problem because when I connected to the wireless network download started and all went well. This wireless is very week and slow therefor I cant use it and I'm stuck with this proxy network which wont work(when I use Chrome for browsing proxy server isn't making any problems ).

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK Manager uses SSL so make sure your proxy is not blocking ports like 443